# Setting up a macro that will format a row from active cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a macro that will format a row. I can make one that formats a specific range, but I am wondering how to format according to the row that I have selected.

I haven't really tried that much because I am extremely beginner to this and wasn't really sure where to start. I didn't want to pull my hair out trying random things. I am barely a coder and simply don't know anyone who can help me out.

```
Range("D131").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TOTAL"
Range("G131").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
Range("F131").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C)"
Range("E131").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C)"
Range("F128").Select
```

So instead of having the D131 range, is there a way to have that value be specific to the cell that is active? and then moving forward to the next cells and formulas accordingly. If I'm not being clear let me know and I will try to explain myself in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        With Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Worksheet.Range("D:G"))
            .FormulaR1C1 = Array("TOTAL", "=SUM(R[-1]C)", "=SUM(R[-1]C)", "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]")
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.